# NDSolve with condition 'bounded at the origin'

Tags: differential-equations

I am trying to solve a Schroedinger equation with `NDSolve` but I only have the boundary condition that the solution is bounded at the origin. How can I solve it? In this simple case `DSolve` can find the solution, but in the more general case I am facing it cannot so I need to use `NDSolve`. Here is the equation:

```
(1/r^2) D[r^2 D[R[r], r], r] -  l (l + 1) R[r] - Z/r R[r] == en R[r]
```

with the constants:

```
en=15
Z=79
l=0 and l=1
```

Comment: How do you solve this equation with `DSolve`? `DSolve` just returns a `DifferentialRoot[…]` without b.c.

Comment: It's a linear equation so you should just be able to have $ R(0) = 1 $ and then multiply but the needed normalization factor after the fact. Couldn't make it would with `NDSolve` though.

Comment: @xzczd  `DSolve` produces a solution in terms of hypergeometric functions, if all three constants are specified.

Comment: When the ODE is singular at the origin, start the computation slightly removed, for instance, `r0 = 10^-4; NDSolveValue[{ode /. {Z -> 79, en -> 15, l -> 0},  R[r0] == 1, R'[r0] == 0}, R[r], {r, r0, 1}]`, where `ode` is the differential equation given in the question.